# latex subsection chapter number on separate page

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I have problems with `\subsection` part in Latex. When I use `\subsection` for specific sections, the chapter number goes in the page beforehand. Here is an image. How to Make Chapter 2 to be on same page with "Implementation"?[image]

My current code:

```
\chapter{Implementation}

\section{Business Understanding}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example

Comment: Please post the code of a *complete*, small document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. You provided just two lines of the document that do not tell anything about the document class and all the settings. Please make sure that your sample document compiles and shows the problem that you want to have solved.

Comment: The \book class makes a difference between even and uneven pages. From the screenshot it looks like that on the "right" side of the book page chaper 3 may already begin. But indeed a MWE as @gernot mentioned is needed.